# SSO integration issue in Mobile app using Cordova

Tags: cordova, web-applications, navigation, single-sign-on, mobile-application

We are having an issue with SSO(Single Sign-On) integration in one of our mobile apps.

The application is available as both a website and a mobile app.
The website has all the APIs and the respective UI in a web application.
The Mobile app is built using Cordova as a wrapper, having its frontend code in the mobile application and it uses APIs(backend) from the web app.

Implemented SSO(Shibboleth, ADFS, CAS) on the website and it is completely up and running. But when coming to the Mobile app, we are facing an issue as it is using backend from the web app.
In the process, when the user lands on the mobile app for login, the user is navigated to his respective SSO login page(third party - client's login page).
Once authentication happens on the client's SSO page, they hit back with their response to our web page(present in the web application). 
So we are facing an issue here in navigating it back to the mobile app since here the communication is not between two but between three things - Mobile app, client SSO page, and then Web app.

If anyone who has worked with Cordova and has knowledge on how to work with such a scenario, please provide your inputs which would be a great help.